# Cast works on one field but not other

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting

I have two fields in my table, Cycle and Idle, both are nvarchar(50) and both contain time.  I am trying to get a total for each field based on a particular program number using TSQL.  Below is a small example of the data.

```
Id      ProgramNo           Cycle       Idle
209702  3998_BOTH_OPPS.MPF  00:02:41    00:00:25
209703  472_7580_OPP1.MPF   00:02:08    00:01:44
209704  3998_BOTH_OPPS.MPF  00:00:27    00:00:11
209705  3998_BOTH_OPPS.MPF  00:00:00    00:00:00
209706  3998_BOTH_OPPS.MPF  00:00:01    00:01:40
209707  9491_OPP1.MPF       00:00:00    00:00:00
209708  9491_OPP1.MPF       00:00:01    00:00:04
209709  9491_OPP1.MPF       00:01:05    00:00:19
```

So for example, get the total Cycle time and Idle time for ProgramNo 3998_BOTH_OPPS.MPF and 9491_OPP1.MPF

This is my query...

```
SELECT
  ProgramNo,
  cast(dateadd(MILLISECOND, sum(datediff(MILLISECOND, 0, cast(Cycle AS DATETIME))), 0) AS TIME) AS CycleTime,
  cast(dateadd(MILLISECOND, sum(datediff(MILLISECOND, 0, cast(Idle AS DATETIME))), 0) AS TIME)  AS IdleTime
FROM Cycle
GROUP BY ProgramNo
```

It works just fine for CycleTime but I get an error for IdleTime:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: it means you have some bad data in the records in that field. Something that cannot be converted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find values that don't match the HH:MM:SS format.

Here is one simplistic method:

```
select idle_time
from cycle
where idle_time not like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
```

If that doesn't work, then look at the components:

```
where (idle_time like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' and
       (not (left(idle_time, 2) between '00' and '23') or
        not substring(idle_time, 4, 2) between '00' and '59') or
        not right(idle_time, 2) between '00' and '59')
       )
```

SQL Server 2012+ makes this much easier with `try_convert()`.

Comment: 2.03:02:07
3.18:15:05
3.21:06:53
3.19:40:03
2.09:20:53

Comment: So it appears that I have a number before the hour followed by a period.  I accidently added the comment above before I had a chance to look at it.  Is there a better suggestion as to how I could total these fields?  I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: @volleygirl029 . . . Please ask another question with appropriate sample data (including the fields with the spaces) and the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, you can fix your data like so:

```
cast(dateadd(MILLISECOND, sum(datediff(MILLISECOND, 0, cast(right(Idle,8) AS DATETIME))), 0) AS TIME) as IdleTime
```

We are just looking at the right most 8 characters... so if there isn't a #. before your time it will still work

```
select right('3.18:15:05',8)
select right('18:15:05',8)
```